# ¿Why appear ML error in evaluating test file?

Tags: testing, syntax-error, ml

I have two elementary programs:

The first one is next (named funct.sml):

```
fun f(x,y) = x * y
fun double x = f(x,2)
```

In the second one I write some tests:

```
use "funct.sml"
val t1 = f(3,5) = 15
val t2 = double 6 = 12
```

when I write, on linux, `sml < test.sml` raise the error:

```
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.80 [built: Fri May 22 11:19:04 2020]
stdIn:2.2-2.8 Error: syntax error: deleting  VAL ID
```

running it on emacs show:

```
[opening test.sml]
test.sml:1.2-1.19 Error: syntax error: deleting  ID STRING

uncaught exception Compile [Compile: "syntax error"]
  raised at: ../compiler/Parse/main/smlfile.sml:15.24-15.46
             ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:42.54
             ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:299.20-299.23
```

these tests work fine making it directly on sml-mode for emacs, then I don't find where could be the error code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you enter the contents of "test.sml" manually in the interpreter, it won't work either. The REPL expects semicolons as terminators.

Comment: Thanks molbdnilo, the tests in REPL I write with semicolons and work fine but making the tests in the test file "test.sml"  don't.

Comment: Yes, that's to be expected. And redirecting with `<` enters the file contents on standard input – that is, into the REPL – so you need semicolons in your file, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot molbdnilo, effectively was a tiny big detail.